What's the xaml-only syntax for setting x:DataType to a type with a generic parameter?
For argument's sake, say I have an object of Lazy<MyType> that I need to set as the x:DataType of an element in XAML.
What I've Tried
Setting x:DataType to a:Lazy doesn't work - it doesn't have the type parameter. It might give an error along the lines of "type "a:Lazy" was not found", or "Incorrect number of type parameters".
a:Lazy<b:MyType> also doesn't work. It seems to treat <b:MyType> as a tag as opposed to a generic parameter.
Non-Viable Solutions
I believe one could create a type to wrap the generic and use that type in the view model, which would be able to be set rather easily in xaml. Something along the lines of public class LazyMyType : Lazy<MyType>;. This isn't a viable solution for my specific use case as it requires edits to the view model, which is not my perview. (Also, seems like a bit of a code smell to me, as it obscures some information about the type).
Question
So, is there a xaml-only solution for setting a generic type as x:DataType - i.e., a solution that doesn't require edits to the view model?

To set x:DataType to a type with a generic parameter, you may take a look at this issue Support compiled bindings for generic ViewModels and this PR. So yes you can do that. Below is a demo to show how to use it,
Let's say you have this generic class,
public class Lazy<MyType>
{
    public MyType Name { get; set; }
}

Here is the xaml to set it,
<Label Text="{Binding Name}" x:DataType="local:Lazy(x:String)" 
   FontSize="Large"
   HorizontalOptions="Center"/>

Please let me know if you have any question!
